# Union - How do you know which union parameter is in use?

Tags: c, unions

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct sched_param {
    union {
        int sched_priority;
        struct rcost_sched_param rcost_params;
    };
};
```

I want to know which of the two parameters is "active". Is there a way for me to do that other than adding a int to the `struct sched_param`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's the tricky part here: You'll have to store the information which union entry to use (e.g. using a single `char` member). Also note that both union entries might not necessarily point to the same locations (as you might expect, e.g. due to packing or endianess), so you can't just read one value and determine whether it's containing a valid value or not, since it's up to the compiler how to implement the struct in the union behind the scenes.

Comment: This is completely misleading. No it is not to the compiler how a `union` is implemented: they overlay the same object with a different type. And all `union` members certainly always have the same address. This is what `union`s are made for.

Comment: Reworded that part a bit.

Comment: not much better. It is really not up to the compiler how to implement `union`s. There is one strict rule: *A union type describes an overlapping nonempty set of member objects, each of
which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.*

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the struct inside. My bad, didn't notice the wording in the last sentence.

Answer (score 5):

```
struct sched_param {
  int type;
  union {
       int sched_priority;
        struct rcost_sched_param rcost_params;
  };
}
```

you can add member named `type`,save the data which parameters is "active"